# Android layout dynamically issue

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to dynamically add a textView and a button into a LinearLayout,  then add this layout into a main layout that setContentView use

So its something like this

T  -  text view

B  -  button

Ltb - layout that contains T and B

Lm  - Main layout that contains Ltb

Then use this.setContentView(Lm) to show to result

Roles:
T must be on the left. 
B must be on right of the screen within the layout

All element above are declared dynamically, without using layout xml

Actual result:
Display fine.  but when I type in text that is longer than the screen width, the Button got pushed outside of the screen and gone.

Problem, is it something my dynamic layout doing wrong ?

Code here:

```
public SearchBar(Context c){
    et=new EditText(c);
    bt=new Button(c);
    et.setHint("added et");
    bt.setText("added btn");


    ll=new LinearLayout(c);
    setLinearLayout();

    et.setLayoutParams(flowLeft());
    bt.setLayoutParams(flowRight());

    ll.addView(et);
    ll.addView(bt);
}


private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams flowRight(){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //params.weight = 1.0f;
        //params.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


    return params;     
}

private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams flowLeft(){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //params.weight = 1.0f;
        //params.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


    return params;     
}

private void setLinearLayout(){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
    ll.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// try this way, hope this will help you...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout ltb = new LinearLayout(this);

        TextView T = new TextView(this);

        Button B =new Button(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams ltbParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams TParms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams BParms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        T.setLayoutParams(TParms);
        B.setLayoutParams(BParms);
        T.setText("Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text");
        B.setText("Button");
        ltb.addView(T);
        ltb.addView(B);
        ltb.setLayoutParams(ltbParams);

        setContentView(ltb);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. This may help you.

```
Ltb.setWeightSum(100);
Ltb.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

T.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,50));

B.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,50));
```